# unable to bypass email verification step using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, email-verification

Hi one of my application is having a email verification step to login and I didt find good success to bypass using selenium. I tried all the below ways.

> drv.manage().addCookie(new Cookie("sfdc_lv2","cookie_value")); **(No success)**

Tried using profiles

> ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
>
> FirefoxProfile ffprofile = profile.getProfile("default"); **(No Success)**

Tried using default profile

> FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile(new File("my_path_to_the_profile.default")); **(No Success)**

None of the above ways did bypassed my email verification step. Any other ways I can try to bypass this step ???

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you be more descriptive in your question

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** by-pass email verification I believe by such methods.

1. What you can do is navigate to another tab and automate the sequence thereon.
2. Just verify the email once and then it wouldn't be required further.(in short use a registered email)